# How to upgrade a NodeJS Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have a NodeJS image based on the official `node` Docker image running in a production environment.

How to keep the NodeJS server up-to-date?

- How do I know when or how often to rebuild and redeploy the docker image? (I'd like to keep it always up to date)
- How do I keep the `npm` packages inside of the Docker image up to date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jenkins to schedule job that create nodejs image on desired interval.

Best way to handle the package and updates for docker images is to create separate tags with all updates. Separate tags for all new updates enable you to rollback in case of any backward compatibility issue.

With this new image create your application image and always run test suite if you want to achieve continuous delivery.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE] - Based on comments from OP**

To get the newest images from Docker, and then deploy them through the following process, you can use the DockerHub API (Based on the Registry HTTP API) to query for tags of an image. Then find the image you use (Alpine, Slim, Whatever) and take it's most recent tag. After this, run through your test pipeline and register that tag as a deploy candidate

```
TOKEN=//curl https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login with credentials
REPO="node"
USERNAME="MyDockerHubUsername"    
TAGS=$(curl -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/${USERNAME}/${REPO}/tags/)
```

Your question is deceptively simple. In reality, *Keep a production image up-to-date* requires a lot more than just updating the image on some interval. To achieve true CI/CD of your image you'll need to run a series of steps each time you want to update.

A successful pipeline (Jenkins, Bamboo, CircleCi, CodePipeline, etc) will incorporate all of these steps. And will, *ideally*, be ran on each commit:

**Static Analysis**

First, analyze your code using a linter (eslint) and some code coverage metric. I won't say what is considered acceptable level of coverage as that is largely opinion based, but at least some amount of coverage should be expected.

**Test (Unit)**

Use something like Karma/Mocha/Cucumber to run unit tests on your code.

**Build**

Now you can build your Docker image. I prefer tools like [Hashicorp's Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/) for building images. 
Since I assume you're running a node server (Express or something like it) from within the container, you may also want to spin up the container and run some local acceptance testing after this stage.

**Register**

After you've accepted local testing of the container, register the image with whichever service you use (ECR, Dockerhub, Nexus) and tag it in some meaningful way.

**Deploy**

Now that you have a functioning container, you'll need to deploy it to your orchestration environment. This might be Kubernetes, Docker Swarm, AWS ECS or whatever. It's important that you don't yet serve traffic to this container, however.

**Test (Integration)**

With the container running in a meaningful test environment (nonprod, stage, test, whatever) you can now run integration tests against it. These would check to make sure it can connect with data tier, or would look for a large occurrence of 500/400 errors.

Don't forget - Security should always be a part of your testing also. This is a good place for that

**Switch**

Now that you've tested in nonprod, you can either deploy to the production env or switch routing to the standing containers which you just tested against. Here you should decide if you'll use green/blue or A/B deployment. If blue/green then start routing all traffic to the new container. If A/B, set up a routing policy based on some ratio. Which ever you use, make sure you have an idea of what failure rate is considered acceptable. Monitor the new deployment for any failures (500 error codes or whatever you think is important) and make sure you have the ability to quickly roll back to the old containers if something goes wrong.

**Acceptance**

After enough time has passed without defects, you can accept the new container as a stable candidate. Retag the image, or save the image tag somewhere with the denotation that it is "stable" and make that the new defacto image for launching.

**Frequency**

Now to answer "How Often". Frequency is a side effect of good iterative development. If your code changes are limited in size and scope, then you should feel very confident in launching whenever code passes tests. Thus, with strong DevOps practices, you'll be able to deploy a new image whenever code is committed to the repo. This might be once, twice or fifty times a day. The number eventually becomes arbitrary.

**Keep NPM Packages Up To Date**

This'll depend on what packages you're using. For public packages, you might want to constrain to a version. Then create pipelines that test certain releases of those packages in a sandbox environment before allowing them into your environment.

For private packages, make sure you have a pipeline for each of those also. The pipeline should run analysis, testing and other important tasks before registering new code with npm or your private repos (Nexus, for example)

Comment: Thanks, but you are describing a process of putting a new release in production, don't you? What I am interested in is keeping the NodeJS server up-to-date (to avoid day-1 vulnerabilities, once NodeJS.org issues a patch). The same for NPM. In other words, our code does not change very often but the underlying NodeJS server does. As an example, on a physical machine I would do a "sudo apt-get upgrade; npm update".

Comment: To expand on the post, you can also run the pipeline on a cron, which'll make sure the server is up-to-date. Then you'll release every day, and on code change.

Comment: Unless you're asking, "How do I deploy docker image separate of code". I.e. a deployment for server images and a deployment for code changes. Which is something I don't suggest you do. The two are functionally dependent and a change in one always has the capacity to break the other

Comment: I think there is still a misunderstanding. Given that I already have a container based on the official `node` image, I'd like to know how to keep the container up-to-date (i.e. perhaps to rebuild it every time a new version of the `node` image appears on the Docker hub). It's not clear to me how to automate upgrading / rebuilding the container every time a new `node` image is released. (That's the first half of my question)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. You can use the Registry API to pull image tags from dockerhub. I updated the post at the top to show how